# Не получается вытянуть название местности

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Здравствуйте. Вопрос: Форма на аяксе в конце когда хочу записать данные в базу записываются только айдишники никак не удается получить сами имена хотя в форме они появляются. Подскажите как их вытянуть а то не соображу никак скорее всего какая то мелочь.
P.S. также может подскажите при потворном выборе страны города в своем поле не заменяются а добавляются.

БД

```
    --
    -- База данных: `select`
    --

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Структура таблицы `city`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city` (
      `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`),
      KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
      KEY `country_id_2` (`country_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;

    --
    -- Дамп данных таблицы `city`
    --

    INSERT INTO `city` (`city_id`, `country_id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Киев'),
    (2, 1, 'Харьков'),
    (3, 1, 'Львов'),
    (4, 2, 'Москва'),
    (5, 2, 'Санкт-Петербург'),
    (6, 2, 'Белгород'),
    (7, 3, 'Минск'),
    (8, 3, 'Брест'),
    (9, 3, 'Могилев'),
    (10, 4, 'Стамбул'),
    (11, 4, 'Анкара'),
    (12, 4, 'Анталия'),
    (13, 5, 'Варшава'),
    (14, 5, 'Краков'),
    (15, 5, 'Лодзь'),
    (16, 6, 'Париж'),
    (17, 6, 'Лион'),
    (18, 6, 'Кале'),
    (19, 7, 'Берлин'),
    (20, 7, 'Лейпциг'),
    (21, 7, 'Дортмунд'),
    (22, 8, 'Лондон'),
    (23, 8, 'Манчестер'),
    (24, 8, 'Дувр'),
    (25, 9, 'Вашингтон'),
    (26, 9, 'Нью-Йорк'),
    (27, 9, 'Лас-Вегас'),
    (28, 10, 'Токио'),
    (29, 10, 'Нагасаки'),
    (30, 10, 'Хиросима');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Структура таблицы `country`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country` (
      `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
      KEY `country_id_2` (`country_id`),
      KEY `country_id_3` (`country_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

    --
    -- Дамп данных таблицы `country`
    --

    INSERT INTO `country` (`country_id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'Украина'),
    (2, 'Россия'),
    (3, 'Белоруссия'),
    (4, 'Турция'),
    (5, 'Польша'),
    (6, 'Франция'),
    (7, 'Германия'),
    (8, 'Англия'),
    (9, 'США'),
    (10, 'Япония');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Структура таблицы `customers`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
      `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

    --
    -- Дамп данных таблицы `customers`
    --

    INSERT INTO `customers` (`customer_id`, `country`, `city`) VALUES
    (1, '2', '6'),
    (2, '1', '1'),
    (3, '3', '8');

    --
    -- Ограничения внешнего ключа сохраненных таблиц
    --

    --
    -- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `city`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `city`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `city_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`country_id`);
```

select.js

```
$("document").ready(function() {
getCountry();
function getCountry() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_country.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $("#country_id").append('<option value="' + item.country_id + '">' + item.name + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
}
getCity();
function getCity(){
    $('#country_id').change(function() {
        var city = $("form").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: "get_city.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: city,
            success: function (data) {
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("#city_id").append('<option value="' + item.city_id + '">' + item.name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
insert();
function insert() {
    $("#send").click (function () {
        var form = $("form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:form,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#var_dump").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
});
```

conect.php

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('select');
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf-8");
```

get_country.php

```
<?php

require_once 'conect.php';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY country_id");

$country = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $country[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($country);
```

get_city.php

```
$country_id = $_POST['country_id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE country_id = $country_id");

$city = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $city[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($city);
```

insert.php

```
        <?php
    require_once 'conect.php';
    //mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (country,city) VALUES ('" .     $_POST['country_id'] . "','" . $_POST['city_id'] . "')");
    //

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo '<pre>';
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="selects.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <table  align="center" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                Страна:<br />
                <select name="country_id" id="country_id" class="StyleSelectBox">
                    <option value="0">- выберите город -</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                    Город:<br />
                <select name="city_id" id="city_id" class="StyleSelectBox">
                    <option value="0">- выберите город -</option>
                </select>
                <input type="button" id="send" value="Отправить данные">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table><br />
    <div align="center" id="selectBoxInfo"></div>
        <p id="var_dump"></p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "записываются только айдишники" - куда записываются? Для элемента `select` в данные формы под соответствующим `name` попадает значение атрибута `value` выбраной опции.

Answer (score 1):

Так как с select'ов выходят только значения опций, лэйблы надо обрабатывать вручную.

Создайте дополнительное скрытое поле, куда будет дозаписываться город:

```
<input type="hidden" name="city_name" id="city_name" />
```

И дополнительным событием изменять его значение:

```
$('#city_id').change(function(){
   $("#city_name").val($('#city_id option:selected').text());
});
```

Для очистки городов после смены страны можно использовать метод .empty():

```
function getCity(){
$('#country_id').change(function() {
    var city = $("form").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_city.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: city,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#city_id").empty(); // Здесь очищаем старый список городов
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                console.log(item.city_id + '">' + item.name);
                $("#city_id").append('<option value="' + item.city_id + '">' + item.name + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
});
}
```